What fish and chips item is this?

I’m in the uk.  When I was young,  sometimes when I used to go to the fish and chips shop i used to have what I think was fish and chips but in a sausage type shape as you can see in the picture.  Actually I think that’s probably the same item.
I remember it had its own taste compared to the regular cod and chips but I could be wrong - this could just be regular cod and chips but in a sausage shape which made it feel like a different item.
I don’t see this in traditional fish and chip shops anymore.  Do you know what’s it’s called and if it was a specific type of fish, or is it just regular tasting fish and chips but the fish has been prepared in a sausage shape?
The batter was like normal batter I’m fish and chips and the size and shape was more like battered sausage.
Thanks.

From the appearance of the cut end, it looks like normal battered fish.

I reckon @KateBunting's right, but that shape is more common in smaller portions.  Fish goujons are another possibility though, but they're normally flatter and smaller still

I suspect that it's from a larger fish whose filets have been cut down to a more reasonable size

Sausages normally have a round cross-section, but the picture shows more of a rectangular cross-section — which would match rumtscho's suggestion of fish fingers.  Also, fish fingers are normally a bit smaller than in the picture, and covered in breadcrumbs.  Can you narrow down the size and coating?

@gidds the coating is definately not like the breadcrumbs of fish fingers it was more like normal batter and the size was not small like fish fingers, it was bigger like  battered sausage.

@Joe (British) fish and chips is always a fillet, usually cod, sometimes haddock, rarely hake.  It's not a useful format for dealing with bones and the typical fish used are large

This looks like cod.  Cod fillets can often be very thick and a whole cod fillet can sometimes be enormous. These are often cut down to smaller sizes.

While cod is probably “the” fish for fish and chips, some places will have a wider menu choices with different kinds of white fish, e.g. haddock, pollock or even plaice.
Different fish species will yield different shaped fillets (plaice being an extreme example), for large fish the filets are cut into smaller pieces and depending on where the piece originates, the filets can be thicker (giving you a more stick- or sausage-like shape when battered and fried) or flatter. The cross-section in your photo shows that the fish came from a rather larger animal, as evidenced by the few large flakes in the flesh. The shape hints at either a back filet (which are more rectangular than the belly side) and/or at being cut longitudinally from a larger piece.
So if you always get cod these days, try another fish and see which one fits the taste you remember from your childhood or prefer today.

yeah, and even if it's listed as cod, more often than not it isn't but something cheaper instead. And more often than not even the chippy doesn't know as they buy their fish pre-cut, never see the actual fish at all.

This is simply cut-up fish. It gets frozen into big block, cut-up, and breaded. The name for it is fish finger.
Here is a description from a company that produces this as a convenience food for home customers. The description is in German, but even if you don't speak it, the pictures might give you a better understanding. https://www.iglo.de/ernaehrung/fisch/fischstaebchen/herstellung

In the UK, fish fingers are usually smaller than in the picture above, and are usually covered in breadcrumbs rather than batter.  (The linked Wikipedia page shows that.)  But it's still a good guess: fish fingers are a common food in the UK, especially for youngsters.

My picture is not what we would refer to in the uk as fish fingers.
The pictures in the link you have provided ARE what we we refer to in the UK as fish fingers and is consistent with Gidds description.  I can clearly see a major differences between my original picture and fish fingers.
you can see the pics are completely different to my original. Have also just seen a ‘chunky fish fingers’ product which looks closer but I still doubt that’s it.

The same principle as for fish fingers is also done for larger pieces, depending on how the large frozen slabs are cut. I think rumtscho simply illustrated a process, not necessarily a product.

@JamesWilson I must say that I don't see the "completely different" pics. OK, so the breading might be different, but this isn't such a huge difference.

to me it just looks like the fish was sliced horizontally and this is the thick half. i have done it that way and this is exactly how it comes out.
